# Rails - Group using 2 tables and count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following models: students , groups_by_student and groups.

A row of students table is city_id, so I have to show an html table

```
            Total      group1     group2     group3
city1         30         10         5         15
city2          2          0         0          2
city3         20         10        10          0
city4          5          0         5          0
city5         10          0         2          8
```

This is what I did:

```
groups = Group.find([1,4,6]) #Array of groups id's

total = []
groups.each do |g|
  total << Student.joins(:groups_by_students).where(:groups_by_students => {:group_id => g.descendants}).count(:group => :city_id)
end

#I'm using AwesomeNestedSet gem, so g.descendants gives group children.
```

So now I have an array of 3 hashes that contain the city id as key and the total of students as the value, but now I'm not sure how to present this data in a html table.

How can I iterate per each "total" element? or is there another way of getting this information?

Thanks in advance

Javier

**EDIT:**

This is the total array

```
total = [
    {city1 =>10, city3 => 10},
    {city1 => 5, city3=>10, city4=>5, city5 => 2},
    {city1 => 15, city2 => 2}
]
```

and now I have to place each in a td label inside a html table with the 0 if theres no value for that group.

Answer (score 0):

I've traversed an array of hashes like;

```
ary.each do |hash| puts "<tr>#{hash.keys} : #{hash.values}</tr>" end
```

Can you hack that to suit your needs? Am afraid your question doesn't provide a lot to work with.

Comment: I updated my question showing what I get in my array. Now I have to adapt that array to my needs, that's what seems to be my main problem

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did, may be it might help you a little bit: (here the total value is the last column though)

```
<table>
<% i = 1%>
<% total = 0%>
<% city=""%>
<% 5.times do %>
<tr>
<% city = 'city'+ "#{i}" %>
<% @total.each do |hash| %>
<% if(hash[city].nil?)%>
<% hash[city] = 0 %>
<%end%>
<% total += hash[city].to_i %>
<td><%= hash[city] %></td>
<%end %>
<td> <%= total %></td>
<% total = 0 %>
<% i += 1 %>
</tr>
<%end%>
</table>
```

Here the row is controlled by city and not the group. Hence i could not find any other way other than a double loop. If you need that total to be printed in the first column and then rest of the information next, then i think you need to display the total first and then loop again and display city values of each group
Also, for this you need to know the number of cities before hand or else we will not know to print '0' for a particular city in a particular group